# How to recursively set permissions for files only?

Tags: command-line, filesystem, chmod

I want to remove executable permission for all files in my home folder, recursively, how to do that using command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
find ~ -type f -exec chmod -x {} \;
```

Comment: It works, thanks, but looks like I've made terrible mistake, now native Steam client won't run and I have to search for its folder or reinstall, and I cant find the right folder

Comment: @Nur Ouch! Try `find ~ -type f -exec bash -c "file \"{}\" | grep executable && chmod +x \"{}\"" \;`

Comment: I'll try it tomorrow, gotta go now, thanks again for your help :D